# Error in Loading Seaborn Built In Data Sets in Google Colab Notebook

Tags: python, dataset, seaborn, google-colaboratory

In the past I have used the built in data sets in Seaborn in a Google Colab Notebook. I was able to access the data sets in a Colab notebook 1 week ago, but now I am no longer able to access them. I get an error message saying that it cannot find the data set that it was able to find using the exact same code a week ago. None of the datasets are working for me now.

I tried the code below

```
penguins = sns.load_dataset("penguins")
```

and I got the following error message

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-8424eff21d6f> in <cell line: 3>()
      1 #Reading in the dataset.
      2 #This is a famous dataset that comes preloaded as a part of seaborne graphing library
----> 3 penguins = sns.load_dataset("penguins")

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/seaborn/utils.py in load_dataset(name, cache, data_home, **kws)
    585         if not os.path.exists(cache_path):
    586             if name not in get_dataset_names():
--> 587                 raise ValueError(f"'{name}' is not one of the example datasets.")
    588             urlretrieve(url, cache_path)
    589         full_path = cache_path

ValueError: 'penguins' is not one of the example datasets.
```

Comment: I can confirm your issue. A workaround is to use `import pandas as pd` and `df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mwaskom/seaborn-data/master/penguins.csv')`, which I have verified.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, issue has been reported  here: [https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/issues/4288] including its  temporary workaround.

You can do the following:

```
!pip install seaborn==0.13.1
Runtime -> restart session
```

It should work.